# Why isn't my angularJS updating correctly in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, updating

So, I'm working on an application with AngularJS routes and parameters. I have my controllers set up, and for some reason when I go to one of the pages my application isn't pulling the array from the angularJS code, nor adding in my items! Any ideas?

Here is my angular:

```
.controller("foodController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.addItem;
    $scope.foodItem = "";

    $scope.foodArray = ['Milk', 'PB&J'];

    //add items here
    $scope.addItem = function () {
        /*if ($scope.foodItem = '') {
            alert('What did the child eat?');
        } else {*/
        $scope.foodArray.push($scope.foodItem);
        $scope.foodItem = '';
    };
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="foodController">

<form ng-submit="addItem()">
    <h1>Food Chart</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="What did the child eat today?" ng-model="foodItem" />
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{{ foodItem }}
<section>
    <h1>Food Log</h1>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in foodArray">
        <td> {{ item }}</td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="removeItem(item)"> Remove Item</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</section>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not seeing where you specify which controller wraps your HTML.

Comment: I left off the body tag when I copy/pasted! My mistake!

Comment: is `{{ foodItem }}` being displayed correctly?

Comment: What about the module definition?  And why do you define `$scope.addItem` twice?

Comment: {{ foodItem }} does display correctly - the array is what is not updating, unfortunately. I didn't see any major issues with it. As far as module definition, that's in another section of the code - up near the top, which I didn't copy/past in. Would it help to have? It's not causing issues on any other page I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a table to iterate over rows with your `tr`

Try this instead:

```
<div ng-controller="foodController">
  <form ng-submit="addItem()">
    <h1>Food Chart</h1>
    <input type="text" placeholder="What did the child eat today?" ng-model="foodItem"/>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  {{ foodItem }}
  <section>
    <h1>Food Log</h1>
    <table>
      <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in foodArray">
        <td> {{ item }}</td>
        <td>
          <button ng-click="removeItem(item)"> Remove Item</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: By the way, I added a div with ng-controller, if you're using routing or have your controller declared outside of the code you provided, remove that div

Comment: THERE we go. Thank you. I haven't spent too much time using tables, which is why I'm trying to use them this project. Thank you so much! Works perfectly now!

Comment: And yes, I just added in the    <table>   and    <tbody>    tags. I can't believe I forgot them!

Answer (score 3):

wrap you tr in a table element

```
<section>
      <h1>Food Log</h1>
      <table>

         <tr ng-repeat="item in foodArray">
        <td> {{ item }}</td>
        <td>
            <button ng-click="removeItem(item)"> Remove Item</button>
        </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

   </section>
```

Here is a working plunk
http://plnkr.co/edit/JYE3tVLubyM6FDbRm54k?p=preview

Comment: I wish I could click "accept" for both of you! Thank you though! I definitely need to do more work with tables and practice with them on my own.